# Como percorrer as tuplas referentes a uma ID e checar seus valores?

Tags: mysql, sql

Em uma tabela onde registro a quantidade de parcelas e a situação de cada uma delas, preciso percorrê-la e encontrar as ordens de venda onde todas as parcelas estão pagas.

Ex:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela_parcelas WHERE ID = X
```

Retorna:

```
ID       Parcela | Situacao  
123456 |  1      | Pago  
123456 |  2      | Pendente 
123456 |  3      | Pendente
000002 |  1      | Pago
000002 |  2      | Pago
```

@edit
Eu preciso verificar na "tabela_parcelas" se todas as parcelas do pedido XXX foram pagas, para que na "tabela_pedidos" eu possa alterar o status da compra para "completo" ou manter "pendente".

Os status possíveis de cada parcela, são:

```
// 00 - pagamento efetuado 
// 01 - pagamento não autorizado/transação recusada 
// 02 - erro no processamento da consulta 
// 03 - pagamento não localizado 
// 10 - campo “idConv” inválido ou nulo 
// 11 - valor informado é inválido, nulo ou não confere com o valor registrado 
// 21 - Pagamento Web não autorizado 
// 22 - erro no processamento da consulta 
// 23 - erro no processamento da consulta
// 24 - Convênio não cadastrado 
// 25 - Convênio não ativo 
// 26 - Convênio não permite debito em conta 
// 27 - Serviço inválido 
// 28 - Boleto emitido 
// 29 - pagamento não efetuado
// 30 - erro no processamento da consulta 
// 99 - Operação cancelada pelo cliente
```

Comment: Marcelo o campo situação é numérico então?

Comment: Sim, @gmsantos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT * FROM `tabela_parcelas ` A1 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * from `tabela_parcelas ` A2 where A1.id = A2.id and A2.situacao <> 0 ) ORDER BY id desc
```

Answer (score 3):

Se ID for numérico

```
SELECT * FROM tabela_parcelas WHERE ID = 2 AND Situacao="Pago"
```

se for string

```
SELECT * FROM tabela_parcelas WHERE ID = "000002" AND Situacao="Pago"
```

Edit: depois do seu comment e tentando adivinhar o que você precisa, talvez seja algo nessa linha (**apenas exemplo, claro**. a sintaxe não é essa):

```
SELECT * FROM tabela_ordens WHERE (SELECT tabela_parcelas (NAO-RETORNA-NADA-PENDENTE") )
```

Aguardo seu edit na pergunta para melhorar a resposta (ou para outros participantes responderem, claro).

Comment: Bacco, meu exemplo foi ridicularmente simples. Irei fazer isso numa tabela e preciso trazer os registros sem referenciar uma ID em especifico como fizemos nos exemplos. Algo como: SELECT * FROM tabela_parcelas WHERE ( verifica todas as linhas do id x e se tiver pago, retorna  o valor). Perdoe-me a confusão.

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade tente editar a pergunta e deixar mais clara a questão (explique de maneira bem objetiva o que quer, de preferencia com o caso concreto, pois pelo comment fiquei na mesma). Estou de saída, mas na volta posso tentar editar a resposta, ou até lá alguém pode dar a resposta adequada ao que você quer (desde que vc seja objetivo, e explique o que quer com clareza, obviamente). O botão "editar" fica logo abaixo da pergunta. Tente ser detalhista para uma melhor chance de obter uma resposta que te atenda.

Comment: Editado, tentei simplificar.

Answer (score 0):

Em vez de buscar tudo que já foi pago, por que não buscar tudo que não tem nada pendente?

```
SELECT * FROM tabela_parcelas WHERE id NOT IN 
(SELECT id FROM tabela_parcelas WHERE situacao = 'Pendente');
```

Exemplo no **[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d32c3/17)**

<sup>Estou assumindo que só existem duas situações: Pago e Pendende. Caso existam outras, no `select` interior é preciso colocar as outras situações usando um `or`</sup>

Conforme os códigos status postados, como são numéricos conforme seu comentário, basta alterar o campo situacao da query para maior que 0.

```
SELECT * FROM tabela_parcelas WHERE id NOT IN 
(SELECT id FROM tabela_parcelas WHERE situacao > 0);
```

Comment: Há outros status. Eu preciso verificar na "tabela_parcelas" se todas as parcelas do pedido XXX foram pagas, para que na "tabela_pedidos" eu possa alterar o status da compra para "completo" ou manter "pendente".

Comment: @marcelo edite sua pergunta incluindo todos os status possíveis.

Comment: inclui a lista com os códigos utilizados.

Comment: Mesmo assim ele ainda traz registros onde há parcelas com pagamentos pendentes, @gmsantos. Exemplo: Quando rodei a query, me retornou o ID 2829 com as parcelas 1 e 2 pagas, porém a 3º continua pendente. Dessa forma não era para ele estar na lista, somente deveria vir se todas as 3 parcelas estivessem pagas.